# pandas data with double quote

Tags: python, pandas, double-quotes

I am trying to read a large dataset in .csv format which is update automatically using the pandas library.
The problem is that in my data, the first row is a string without double quotation marks, and the other colums are strings with double quotation marks. It is not possible for me to adjust the .csv file manually.

A simplified dataset would look like this

1. A,"B","C","D"
2. comp_a,"tree","house","door"
3. comp_b,"truck","red","blue"

I need the data to be stored as separate columns without the quotation marks like this:

1. A       B      C      D
2. comp_a  tree   house  door
3. comp_b  truck  red    blue

I tried using

```
import pandas as pd
df_csv = pd.read(path_to_file,delimiter=',')
```

which gives me the complete header as a single variable for the last column

1. A,"B","C","D"
2. comp_a  "tree"   "house"  "door"
3. comp_b  "truck"  "red"    "blue"

The closest result to the one i need was by using the following

```
df_csv = pd.read(path_to_file,delimiter=',',quoting=3)
```

which correctly recognizes each column, but adds in a bunch of extra double quotes.

1. "A        ""B""      ""C""      ""D"""
2. "comp_a   ""tree""   ""house""  ""door"""
3. "comp_b   ""truck""  ""red""    ""blue"""

Setting quoting to a value from 0 to 2 just reads an entire row as a single column.

Does anyone know how I can remove all quotation marks when reading the .csv file?

Comment: Are you sure you are using pd.read? If I have a csv-file containing your three lines with mixed quotation marks, `pd.read_csv` reads it without any problems.

Comment: To avoid any miscommunication, the first row (A,"B","C","D") is the header of my datafile and these are the values i want to read in as the column names.

Comment: That is how I understood it and how pd.read_csv should read it with the default parameters. Which pandas version are you using? Can you post the return value from `pd.__version__`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just load the data with `pd.read_csv()` and then use `.replace('"','', regex=True)`

In one line it would be:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',').replace('"','', regex=True)
```

To set the columns names:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
```

And drop row 0:

```
df = df.drop(index=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Do you think `df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',').replace('"','', regex=True)` ?

Comment: yeah i had tested on a series initially

Comment: When i try this, it removes the double quotes from the data correctly, so thank you for that. However, as the A,"B","C","D" row is the header of my datafile and thus I would like to use that as the column names, it still gives me just a single column which is named A,"B","C","D" instead of a single column named A, another named B etc.
Sorry if I was not clear about the header part in my original question

Comment: @Gerrit ok now I see... then you just rename the columns and then drop the initial row and reset the index

Answer (score 2):

you can replace `"` after `read_csv` and save that file again using `df_csv.to_csv('fname')`

```
df_csv.apply(lambda x:x.str.replace('"', ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider your data in a file data.csv like

```
$> more data.csv 
A,"B","C","D"
comp_a,"tree","house","door"
comp_b,"truck","red","blue"
```

Perhaps a newer pandas version would solve your problem from itself, e.g. at `pd.__version__ = '0.23.1'`

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: pd.read_csv('data.csv')
Out[2]: 
        A      B      C     D
0  comp_a   tree  house  door
1  comp_b  truck    red  blue
```

Otherwise apply a replace on the read-out

```
pd.read_csv('data.csv').replace('"', '')
```