# Pandas, remove outer quote marks from specific columns on export?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a specific problem, we are moving our from old to a new system. Old databse was adjusted to a new one with Pandas. However, I am facing a problem.

If file opened with SQL or Csv, it has outer quotes,
`"UUID_TO_BIN('5e6f7922-8ae9-11ea-a3bd-888888888788', true)"`

I need to make sure it has no upper quotes like this:
`UUID_TO_BIN('5e6f7922-8ae9-11ea-a3bd-888888888788', true)`

What could be pandas solution to do this for specific columns, on exporting saving to SQL or csv? Because now it's as a string and returns like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas data with double quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359010/pandas-data-with-double-quote)

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is that the old system produces files like .csv with the quotes, you might just want to edit the .csv file itself as described [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32756/removing-special-character-from-csv-file)

If your problem is that pandas saves it as a string with double quotes you can either run the same thing on the csv output of pandas, or you could pass the .to_csv() function the argument

```
quotechar=''
```

for which you can find more info [on this page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try to read your data in Pandas using:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',').replace('"','', regex=True)
```

This reading line should remove the `" "` from your data.