# Keep running into this issue inserting a bang in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Thanks for reading. I'm working with this code right here:

```
df=client.query(SQL).to_dataframe()
df.insert(0,"bang", '\"!\"', allow_duplicates=True)
```

When I run it in Google Colabs/Python/Pandas, I get this:
"""!"""

I really need just one quotation like this:
"!".

Let me know if you guys have ever encountered this issue.

Comment: Hrm.. try `df.insert(0,"bang", r'\"!\"', allow_duplicates=True)` Reason why this may work... https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081640/6361531

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with pandas, but in somethings like the [excel dialect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect) of python's csv package, a specific alternative escape sequence is preferred. Like double-quotes being escaped by another double-quote.

There does already seem to be some [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359010/pandas-data-with-double-quote) examining this.

Comment: Simple resolution: Just use the + Operator to add the strings together.

Comment: @DylanJaramillo, ah, so more like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20027386/3003133 ?