# Pandas read_csv appending "" to some columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am reading a file with pandas but it is appending " to some columns. All I am doing is reading file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('biosas.csv')
```

In csv file

[image]

After reading

```
Name    "Sex"   "Age"   "Height (in)"   "Weight (lbs)"
0   Alex    "M" 41  74  170
1   Bert    "M" 42  68  166
```

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359010/pandas-data-with-double-quote